# How many times 'X' sequence repeat on ArrayList

Tags: java, algorithm

Supposing I have the following sequence in my `ArrayList<Integer>`

1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4
5
6

I need to know how many times the sequence (1,2,3,4) appears on the list.

For this example, the answer would be 2!

I need 2 solutions, one, numbers NEED to be in the following sequence (1,2,3,4)
and another without following a sequence (4,1,2,3)

I'm using Java, thanks in advance.

What I tried:
Check for sequence, and if it's true:

```
        AnotherList.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
        AnotherList.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
        AnotherList.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
        AnotherList.add(Integer.valueOf(4));
        if(TheList.containsAll(AnotherList))
            TheList.removeAll(AnotherList);
```

But when I do it, it removes all 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s that are in my list.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware of this or not but you can't just come on here and convey the message: "I have a problem, I've attempted nothing at all, I put 0 effort in trying to solve my problem and I want you to do it for me". Have you tried anything? Once you try something and if your code doesn't work, then you may ask a question.

Comment: Well, Actually I tried something by removing the number from the ArrayList, but it removes them all if they repeat.

Comment: At least post the code you have so people know you've made an effort, regardless of how minimal.

Comment: what if the sequence is (1,1,1) and your arraylist contains (1,1,1,1) is that counted as twice or once?

Comment: alright, there it is.

Comment: Don't post a description of what your code does; post your actual code. (The entire thing)

Comment: as it wasn't working for me, I erased it all and I don't have the code anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you should rewrite the code and then if it doesn't work, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: ok, there it is, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Jonie, that should be count as one.

Comment: Might help to read the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  `containsAll` does not do what you need.  It returns true if each element in `AnotherList` is _somewhere_ in the `ArrayList`.  They don't have to be in sequence.  There are some methods documented there that will be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

On the presumption that you can't overlap counts (so 1,1,1,1 in list with (1,1,1) as sequence gives you 1).

In algorithm so you can code it yourself (I won't give you the psuedocode until I see solid progress on the problem):

Use a loop, see if current number in list matches the first number in sequence. If it doesn't match, move to next number in list. If it matches, move to next number in list but also increment to next number in sequence. If all numbers in sequence are matched, add 1 to count. Return count after reaching end of list.

Second part, make a list of all combinations of your sequence (Use a stack or recursion). Do the same as before, but comparing with every item in the combination list until you get a complete match. Once matched, jump to end of last matched character in list and repeat.

Comment: well, using loops and ifs I think can do that, but I thought that would be a more sophisticated way, like something we can do on .net using LINQ.

Comment: sadly there's no exact equivalent in java for LINQ. You could get external libraries that are similar. If you want cleverer methods, try using .sublist and .equals for arraylist with a loop (which allows you to extract sublist and then compare two lists).